# Encrypt JSON with SHA256 hash, got 512 characters back instead of 64

Tags: python, encryption, hash, cryptography, rsa

Based on [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt-rsa#kms-howto-encrypt-rsa-python) and [cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/?highlight=decryption#decryption).

I attempt to encrypt a queried result which is in a JSON format which look like this {"data":"abc"}. As I know, when encrypting with SHA256, the encrypted data will be in a form of 64 characters but after I looked on and tried it with the code in the link and some modification, I got a result of 512 characters instead of 64 characters.

This is my code:

```
def encrypt_rsa(_rsa_pub, plaintext):
    key_txt = _rsa_pub.encode()
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(key_txt, default_backend())

    # encrypt plaintext
    pad = padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                       algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                       label=None)
    return public_key.encrypt(plaintext, pad)

pk = ....#public key
message = .... #query result (JSON)
x = json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')
enc = encrypt_rsa(pk , x)
enc = base64.b64encode(enc).decode()
dec = decrypt_rsa(enc)
```

There is no error but I got a long encrypted data with 512 characters which is really weird. I have tried decrypting it with the code from [cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/?highlight=decryption#decryption) and got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decrypt'
```

which I think this error might occured because of the wrong encrypted data that should be 64 characters but the input is 512 characters. So, based on my case, what did I forgot or what should be add to this code to make it become an encrypted data with 64 characters that can be decrypted?

Edit: decrypt function

```
def decrypt_rsa(ciphertext):
    private_key = .....
    pad = padding.OAEP(mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
                   algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
                   label=None)
    return private_key.decrypt(ciphertext, pad)
```

The error occured at `decrypt` at the line that return the result. I actually passed the encrypted data into this function. And I think it not because of the key since it should not provide error result like this

Comment: in this line`algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),` are you sure it shouldnt be `algorithm=hashes.SHA256,` ?

Comment: I copied from google document so .. yeah (link above)

Comment: @Nullman: A reasonable guess, but I'm familiar with the package and he has that part correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are encrypting data with RSA. (Not SHA256, that's just a parameter of the RSA encryption.) Note that RSA is typically only used to encrypt/decrypt very small amounts of data. Typically it is used to encrypt/decrypt another symmetric key, e.g. for AES, and then the bulk encryption/decryption is done with AES.

The size of the RSA cipher text is determined by the RSA key size. In this case you are probably using a 4096 bit RSA keys, which results in 4096 / 8 = 512 byte messages. Messages that are smaller are OK, those are padded. Messages that are larger will not work.

Finally, you are trying to call `decrypt` on a string, which is not a thing. You need to pass the data to a `decrypt_rsa` function instead, which does the reverse of the `encrypt_rsa` function that you've shown.

*edit, after decrypt_rsa function added to question*: the error message shows that `private_key` is not actually a private key as it should be, but a string. Why that is we can't say because the code to initialize `private_key` is not shown.

Comment: How large that will make this not work? I actually have to encrypt a JSON with larger than this example. By the way, I updated the question according to your last paragraph about decrypt function. I really passed the encrypted data to decrypt function

Comment: Messages larger that 512 bytes will not work. (The limit may actually be a bit smaller, the padding may add some overhead. Also, utf-8 will take more than one byte per character for characters that are not in the lower ASCII set.)

Comment: For OAEP with sha256 as in this case, the message maximum is 512 - 2*32 - 2 = 446 bytes.

Comment: In your edit, you mean the key is wrong or how I declare variable is wrong? I used `private_key = 'randomblahblah' ` for declaring a variable. I am not the one that create the private key but I think that the key is legit

Comment: @Jamiewp: No, that key is not a legitimate private key. A string may be the base64 or other encoding of data that can be used or supplied to de-serialize a private key, but a private key is an instance of a particular class in the cryptography module. See the [serialization](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#) module.

Comment: You mean that  private_key is not a variable that store  my private key but I need to do something (like I did with public_key variable in encrypt_rsa() function?)

Comment: @Jamiewp: exactly.

Comment: Doing `key_txt = 'actualprivatekey...'.encode()` and
`private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(key_txt, password=None, backend=default_backend())` but got this error `ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.`

Comment: Oh I just saw that I created a public key with 3972 bit rsa so it still should not be 512 right?